# Unable to load a workflow as a service using launchctl in macOS

Tags: applescript, automator, permission

I am trying to load a workflow as a service using launchctl on macOS (Ventura 13.2.1), but I am encountering an error message. The workflow is located at /Users/rohan/Library/Services/open-bluetooth-pane.workflow/Contents/Info.plist.

When I run the command

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Users/rohan/Library/Services/open-bluetooth-pane.workflow/Contents/Info.plist
```

I get the error message "Path had bad ownership/permissions" (Load failed: 122). I have checked the permissions of the folders and files involved, but everything seems to be correct.

I set the permission using following

```
sudo chown -R rohan:staff /Users/rohan/Library/Services/open-bluetooth-pane.workflow
sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/rohan/Library/Services/open-bluetooth-pane.workflow
```

Trying to create a simple service using automator and configured it to run the applescript which in turns runs the a shell script to open the Bluetooth pane.

Here is the applescript

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    do shell script "/Users/rohan/Documents/bluetooth-settings.sh"
    
    return input
end run
```

here is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Bluetooth.prefPane
```

Code inside Info.plist

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>NSServices</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>NSBackgroundColorName</key>
                        <string>background</string>
                        <key>NSIconName</key>
                        <string>NSActionTemplate</string>
                        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>default</key>
                                <string>open-bluetooth-pane</string>
                        </dict>
                        <key>NSMessage</key>
                        <string>runWorkflowAsService</string>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you show what's inside `Info.plist` ?

Comment: Also can you exmplain exactly what you want to achieve? Because I can see your script will open Bluetooth settings. Why not running it directly, but via launchctl?

Comment: I'm creating it as service so i can add a shortcut to it, and open Bluetooth pane with keyboard shortcut, rather opening spotlight search and type Bluetooth, just saving some keystrock, since I switch Bluetooth devices frequently.

Comment: Update the description for code inside Info.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need launchctl to assign any keyboard shortcuts.
Simply create a new Shortcut in Shortcuts.app like so:
[image: Shortcuts app with open Bluetooth shell script]

Here you can see, that you can assign global keyboard shortcut that will run this service.

Back to launchctl. The plist file that is loaded by launchctl is not the `Info.plist` file. It has a special structure like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.apple.Spotlight</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight</string>
        </array>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is the [Apple Website](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) that explains the keys used in that plist file.

Comment: A far better approach.

Comment: This shortcut worked perfect, Thanks a lot. Just one question, it works from finder, not when I am on desktop, in vs code, in google chrome.

Comment: Have you selected "Services Menu" in "Details"? I can run the keyboard shortcut from any app